# Changing content of a DIV: different span parts

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Suppose I have the following DIV:

```
<div id=div5><span id="name">Hertog-Jan</span><span id="price"></span></div><br>
```

It has two 'parts', the first being the name (which should NEVER change), the second being the price. Ultimately, I have to use an API to retrieve the actually price for Hertog-Jan from the website of the Dutch store 'Albert Heijn', but for know, I use a random number generator to generate a random number between 100 and 999, and make that the 'price':

```
<script>
  function price (it) {
    var value = (Math.round(((Math.random() * 900) + 100)));
    /* value *= 0.01; */
    document.getElementById(it).innerHTML.price += ": €" + value;
  }
```

(maybe not the best) and then call the function like this

```
price('div5');
```

However, the output will always be Hertog-Jan (no price appearing). Am I doing something wrong? I personally think it has to do with the innerHMTL.price, but I'm not sure. I used to have

```
<div id=div5>Hertog-Jan</div><br>
```

but later I have to add an option to sort by name, price, etc. so I thought it would be useful to have the name and price information in two separate, uhm, 'boxes' (you get the idea).

Some of you may have noted that value *= 0.01 is now basically 'turned off', which is due to the fact that sometimes, if a number (such as 626) is multiplied by 0.01, it doesn't give me 6.26, but rather 6.260000000001. Is there any way to fix this? I want random numbers between 1 and 10 (including 1, excluding 10) rounded to exactly two decimals (and it should ALWAYS be two decimals, of course).

Comment: I don't think you need innerHTML.price, price is not a property of innerHTML, it's the id which you've used in .getElementById, just .innerHTML will be fine

Comment: You should only have unique IDs on a page. If there is only one 'price' you can simply do `document.getElementById('price').innerHTML =` otherwise you'll need a way to create unique IDs for each price container (`div5price`, perhaps).

Comment: There is ALOT of problems in the code: 1. you should use unique id's . and since theres normaly not 1 price you should change to `class="price"`
same for `id="name"` . use`class="name"`

2. you are missing `"` in your id. it should be `<div id="div5">Hertog-Jan</div><br>` not the added `"`

3. the `.price`doesnt make any sense nor does the `getElementById`. What you need is `[document.querySelector()]`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

3. You cant simply use `+= ": €" + value;` you cant add a number to a string value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've changed `id` to `class` and added the `" `. The div is now

`<div id="div5"><span class="name">Hertog-Jan: €</span><span class="price"></span></div><br>`

The part where the price is supposed to be inserted is now
`document.getElementById(it).price = value;`
but I do not understand what you mean by `[document.querySelector()]`, though (I'm not very experienced with HTML yet). Is this method of putting the number in 'price' allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if took some time to fix your code with only raw Javscript (im used to using jquery all the time).

https://jsfiddle.net/7omqk3qs/

```
function price (it) {
   var elem = document.querySelector('#'+it+' .price');
   var value = (Math.round(((Math.random() * 900) + 100)));
   console.log(value+' ->random Number');
   /* value *= 0.01; */
   var oldValue = parseInt(elem.innerHTML);

  elem.innerHTML = oldValue + value +' €';
}
```

just ignore the "console.log" its for debugging.

What this does is: first you need to parse an id name . in this example your `div5`. It then searches for an Element with `class=price` (see : `querySelector(...' .price')` ).

Then Random number (for whatever u need this :D)

next up it fetches the old value with `parseInt()` so u dont get a String

Last it changes the HTML content of the `price-<span>` to oldValue = value.

Check the jsFiddle for further information

Hope I could help you

Comment: Great :D Only does this produce, for instance, `Hertog-Jan: €NaN`. You should simply do `parseInt(elem.innerHTML` and then `elem.innerHTML = value;`, and then it works like a charm :)

Comment: good to hear that you were able to get it :D
a tag as `answered` for my answered would be very kind

Answer (score 0):

Just try using

```
document.getElementById(it).innerHTML += ": €" + value;
```

You don't need to put the id name at the end of the property because .price isn't a property of .innerHTML